# ThreeJS LOD clone()

Tags: three.js

In threejs, `LOD` objects created with `clone()` method show all levels of details at once.

If i have two LODs, named LOD1 & LOD2, if LOD2 is a clone of the first and that both are updated in the render loop, then LOD1 will behave as expected. But LOD2 will yet display an instance of all level meshes at the nearest distance, and add an other instance of those mesh if it is the current one.

Did i miss something or is it an issue ?

Comment: Your second LOD has 6 children. Perhaps it would be wise to file a [bug report](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: Im guessing here maybe the second lod has became a mesh?, is lod cloning supported

Comment: Indeed @Careen, as WestLangley suggested i submitted the issue on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until next revision it can be solved by removing or commenting

```
THREE.Object3D.prototype.clone.call( this, object );
```

in

```
THREE.LOD.prototype.clone
```